# How to prevent Chrome/FF blocking CDN fonts due to CORS policy?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cors, cross-domain

I have just migrated a (Wordpress) site to a new hosting location.

The site works perfectly, except that Chrome and Firefox are not displaying certain fonts.

```
Access to Font at 'http://example.com/site/wp-content/themes/mytheme/fonts/modules.ttf' 
from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am using Cloudfront to serve the fonts (I am using example.com as the origin, not S3). The Wordpress .htaccess contains the following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

# Web fonts
AddType application/font-woff woff
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot

AddType application/x-font-ttf ttc ttf
AddType font/opentype otf

AddType     image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz

</IfModule>
```

What is a sensible approach to debug/resolve this?

Comment: As I understand, you put .htaccess on WordPress side, right? But it should be on "server" side, where fonts are located. According to CORS, owner of the resources (fonts) grants access to client servers (WordPress sites).

Comment: Thanks @KAGGDesign, I'm new to this and not explaining very well. As I understand it the Wordpress site *is* the server. The CDN's origin is the Wordpress site. If eg I were hosting the fonts in an S3 bucket, it is relatively straight forward to add access policy to that bucket. But with the WP site being the origin, I'm unclear how to configure things.

Comment: Also odd that Safari loads the fonts without problem

Comment: Unlike other browsers Safari doesn’t (currently) enforce CORS restrictions for @font-face

Comment: thanks @sideshowbarker, I didn't think that Chrome was too strict with CORS restrictions for fonts. But perhaps that has changed?

Comment: Does anyone know whether the above .htaccess is a sensible way to tackle this issue? Or am I on completely the wrong track here?

Comment: The Apache configuration directives in that .htaccess file should result in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header getting sent as expected—as long as the directives are in the right file in the right place. But from the data in the question we can’t determine for certain whether those directives are in the right place. For example, if they’re in a user .htaccess file, maybe there is some server override that prevents user .htaccess files from having any effect, or that prevents certain directives from having any effect. Or maybe the .htaccess file is just not in the right place.

Comment: The .htaccess is in the root of the WP installation. What is the best way to check the headers that are actually applied to the font? Or the best way to find the information that you mention?

Comment: If I `curl -I` the font from cdn.example.com or directly from example.com (thought that cached files may be causing problems!) I do not see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response. I guess the Apache config is not being applied, but how to determine why?

Answer (score 0):

After much Googling and experimenting, it turns out that I needed to enable the mod_headers module on the new server.

```
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Posting here to hopefully save someone else some headache in the future.